# Python get random key in a dictionary in O(1)

Tags: python, data-structures

I need a data structure that supports FAST insertion and deletion of (key, value) pairs, as well as "get random key", which does the same thing as random.choice(dict.keys()) for a dictionary.  I've searched on the internet, and most people seem to be satisfied with the random.choice(dict.keys()) approach, despite it being linear time.

I'm aware that implementing this faster is *possible*:

- I could use a resizing hash table.  If I maintain that the ratio of keys to slots is between 1 and 2, then I can just choose random indices until I hit a non-empty slot.  I only look at 1 to 2 keys, in expectation.
- I can get these operations in guaranteed worst case O(log n) using an AVL tree, augmenting with rank.

Is there any easy way to get this in Python, though?  It seems like there should be!

Comment: Here's an idea: keep another `dict` of the form `{i: key}`, where `i` is a counter. Then, to do a random lookup, call `randint` on this other dictionary. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this sounds like O(1).

Comment: Well, it's not obvious how to do insertion and deletion, from what you said.  However, this does work, to an extent.  Keep track of the maximum counter value, call it n.  For insertions, we first try 2 (or 5, or any constant number of) random values between 1 and n.  If they were both taken, use n and increment the max counter value.  Otherwise, insert at the empty one.  Neat!

Comment: I'm curious as to the intended use of this data structure. What's the use case?

Comment: Not easy to explain.  500 character version:  I'm writing a compiler for a probabilistic programming language (see [link](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/church/wiki/Church)), and inference requires a random walk over possible choices of randomness (see [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm)).  There is a complicated labeling system of execution points of a program, where randomness occurs.  These labels are the keys in my dictionary.  To do inference requires insertion, deletion, and "get random key" (in order use the proposal density in Metropolis-Hastings).

Answer (score 5):

[*edit*: Completely rewritten, but keeping question here with comments intact.]

Below is the realization of a dictionary wrapper with O(1) get/insert/delete, and O(1) picking of a random element.

The main idea is that we want to have an O(1) but arbitrary map from `range(len(mapping))` to the keys. This will let us get `random.randrange(len(mapping))`, and pass it through the mapping.

This is very difficult to implement until you realize that we can take advantage of the fact that **the mapping can be arbitrary**. *The key idea to achieve a hard bound of O(1) time is this: whenever you delete an element, you swap it with the highest arbitrary-id element, and update any pointers.*

```
class RandomChoiceDict(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mapping = {}  # wraps a dictionary
                           # e.g. {'a':'Alice', 'b':'Bob', 'c':'Carrie'}

        # the arbitrary mapping mentioned above
        self.idToKey = {}  # e.g. {0:'a', 1:'c' 2:'b'}, 
                           #      or {0:'b', 1:'a' 2:'c'}, etc.

        self.keyToId = {}  # needed to help delete elements
```

Get, set, and delete:

```
    def __getitem__(self, key):  # O(1)
        return self.mapping[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):  # O(1)
        if key in self.mapping:
            self.mapping[key] = value
        else: # new item
            newId = len(self.mapping)

            self.mapping[key] = value

            # add it to the arbitrary bijection
            self.idToKey[newId] = key
            self.keyToId[key] = newId

    def __delitem__(self, key):  # O(1)
        del self.mapping[key]  # O(1) average case
                               # see http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

        emptyId = self.keyToId[key]
        largestId = len(self.mapping)  # about to be deleted
        largestIdKey = self.idToKey[largestId]  # going to store this in empty Id

        # swap deleted element with highest-id element in arbitrary map:
        self.idToKey[emptyId] = largestIdKey
        self.keyToId[largestIdKey] = emptyId

        del self.keyToId[key]
        del self.idToKey[largestId]
```

Picking a random (key,element):

```
    def randomItem(self):  # O(1)
        r = random.randrange(len(self.mapping))
        k = self.idToKey[r]
        return (k, self.mapping[k])
```

Comment: This is unnecessary. A dictionary is basically the same as a set of keys except they also have values.

Comment: Keep a `list` of the keys, not a `set`.

Comment: @WolframH a list would take linear time to update when a key is added or removed.

Comment: @WolframH: ah, thank you, I misread "random" as "arbitrary. That should work nicely.

Comment: Why list? I agree, a set is the right thing thanks to set.pop() which pops a random element from the set. But, that will be double memory consumption for keys.

Comment: @Matt: 1) then please provide a way to in O(1) achieve the set() API on a dictionary's keys, 2) a list only takes linear time to update if insertions are done in the center. (Not sure how inefficient python's implementation is.) That said, I agree with you about deletions, though WolframH notes (I believe correctly) that it can be made amortized O(1).

Comment: @Matt: It's amortized O(1) (obviously possibly depending on the implementation).

Comment: @BasicWolf: No, `set.pop` is not random.

Comment: set.pop.__doc__
'Remove and return an arbitrary set element.\nRaises KeyError if the set is empty.'

Comment: @BasicWolf: that's what I originally was thinking, but arbitrary is not random, and I believe the OP wants a uniform distribution.

Comment: @BasicWolf: If I were to `.pop()` from `set(range(10))` (in 2.7.2), I would get `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...]`. Arbitrary, maybe, but definitely not random.

Comment: Well, it can't be "Fast, Good and Cheap" at the same time :) But anyway, my bad and thank you for explaining.

Comment: Ok well removing from the list would still be linear.

Comment: you forgot to include the `self` argument on all the methods

Comment: @BasicWolf: It can be "Fast, Good and Cheap" at the same time, just edited. =)

Comment: Why not store the id in the same dictionary as the values?

Comment: @WuTheFWasThat: The issue with making it a list in CPython is that it wouldn't then be able to do O(1) deletions. Generally it should be able to if the programming language is well implemented, if you are deleting only from the end or beginning of the list, but CPython does not claim to be able to do so in O(1) time. Though perhaps my source is just not being specific enough: http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity Since CPython can `append` in O(1) time it can probably delete in O(1) time from the end, but the source did not say.

Comment: @ninjagecko At any rate, I think I'll be implementing your solution, so thanks! :)  Should we get rid of all the comments about the version that didn't work though?  (I'm not a stackoverflow regular, and I'm not sure whether the philosophy is to keep everything, or only useful discussions)

Comment: @WuTheFWasThat: the philosophy is to keep everything that is useful and not misleadingly incorrect or irrelevant. If something claims to do something but doesn't, or misinterprets the question, that usually gets downvoted/deleted. The useful stuff gets upvoted naturally.

Comment: @ninjagecko It seems like many of the above comments (as well as these last few) are useless and even misleading, since you edited the code drastically.  Should we have them deleted then?  I'm guessing we can't do it?

Comment: @ninjagecko I also have much cleaner code for this, now.  Not sure how to share it, since there isn't private messaging.

Comment: Seems like I already answered effectively the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575905/how-to-design-a-data-structure-that-allows-one-to-search-insert-and-delete-an-i , with some additional requirements about initialization. No wonder it seemed familiar...

Answer (score 5):

This may not specifically relevant to the specific use case listed above, but this is the question I get when searching for a way to nicely get a hold of "any" key in a dictionary.

If you don't need a truly random choice, but just need some arbitrary key, here are two simple options I've found:

```
key = next(iter(d))    # may be a little expensive, but presumably O(1)
```

The second is really useful only if you're happy to consume the key+value from the dictionary, and due to the mutation(s) will not be as algorithmically efficient:

```
key, value = d.popitem()     # may not be O(1) especially if next step
if MUST_LEAVE_VALUE:
    d[key] = value
```

Comment: `next(iter(d))` works on Python3 as well as Python2 (instead of `d.iterkeys().next()`)

Comment: @kd88 Thanks! I updated my answer to incorporate that tip.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a somewhat convoluted approach:

- Assign an index to each key, storing it with the value in the dictionary.
- Keep an integer representing the next index (let's call this next_index).
- Keep a linked list of removed indices (gaps).
- Keep a dictionary mapping the indices to keys.
- When adding a key, check the use (and remove) the first index in the linked list as the index, or if the list is empty use and increment next_index. Then add the key, value, and index to the dictionary (`dictionary[key] = (index, value)`) and add the key to the index-to-key dictionary (`indexdict[index] = key`).
- When removing a key, get the index from the dictionary, remove the key from the dictionary, remove the index from the index-to-key dictionary, and insert the index to the front of the linked list.
- To get a random key, get a random integer using something like `random.randrange(0, next_index)`. If the index is not in the key-to-index dictionary, re-try (this should be rare).

Here is an implementation:

```
import random

class RandomDict(object):
    def __init__(self): # O(1)
        self.dictionary = {}
        self.indexdict = {}
        self.next_index = 0
        self.removed_indices = None
        self.len = 0

    def __len__(self): # might as well include this
        return self.len

    def __getitem__(self, key): # O(1)
        return self.dictionary[key][1]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value): # O(1)
        if key in self.dictionary: # O(1)
            self.dictionary[key][1] = value # O(1)
            return
        if self.removed_indices is None:
            index = self.next_index
            self.next_index += 1
        else:
            index = self.removed_indices[0]
            self.removed_indices = self.removed_indices[1]
        self.dictionary[key] = [index, value] # O(1)
        self.indexdict[index] = key # O(1)
        self.len += 1

    def __delitem__(self, key): # O(1)
        index = self.dictionary[key][0] # O(1)
        del self.dictionary[key] # O(1)
        del self.indexdict[index] # O(1)
        self.removed_indices = (index, self.removed_indices)
        self.len -= 1

    def random_key(self): # O(log(next_item/len))
        if self.len == 0: # which is usually close to O(1)
            raise KeyError
        while True:
            r = random.randrange(0, self.next_index)
            if r in self.indexdict:
                return self.indexdict[r]
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, this will work.  Don't know why I didn't think of it.

Hmm... it doesn't do well if you do a lot of deletes, so that next_index is much larger than the number of items.  This can actually happen sometimes in my program.  However, I can optimize so that this isn't an issue.

Comment: @WuTheFWasThat Yeah, I couldn't think of an easy way around that. At least when you add things after deleting, it reuses their indices.

Comment: I don't believe this will result in an O(1) `random_key()` function. For example, if you insert 1000000 elements and delete 1000000 elements, each call to `random_key` will result in a 1/1000000 chance of success despite having a handful of elements in the mapping.

Comment: @ninjagecko You are right, we were just discussing that. (Although technically you are wrong, `1000000 - 1000000 = 0`, so it will raise an exception right away. You probably meant delete 999999 elements.)

Comment: @ninjagecko - Yeah, I think Matt and I were both aware of this problem.  Here is a solution which is no worse than hash-table resizing, but doesn't involve re-implementing dictionaries:  Keep track of the number of things in the table.  When it goes below  next_index / 2, rebuild your whole indexing system with new_next_index = next_index/2, using indices 1, ... , new_next_index for the guys in the table

Comment: Well, I feel lazy for having not thought about it more earlier, since it turned out there were at least two simple solutions.  But at least this is on the internet now!  :)

Comment: @WuTheFWasThat If you're going to do that, I suggest waiting even longer, till `len < next_index/x`, where x should be something like 4, 8, 16, or even more. You should test around for the optimal value.

Comment: I removed "This has the advantage over ninjagecko's implementation because it reuses removed indices, and also has only hard O(1) operations (not amortized)." because it was no longer the case. Hope you don't mind. Thank you.

Comment: @Matt Yeah, you're right.  Getting a random key will be O(x) time average case, but x = 8 or 16 is certainly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

To get O(1) space you need an array data structure and a dictionary that stores values in the array and their indices.

Then when adding values you simply push them onto your array and dictionary with its index in the array.

Then you have acces randomly since you are using array data structure.

When removing values you look at the index of the value you want to remove in the dictionary. Then replace that value in the array with the last value in the array (make sure it is not the last element already) and pop() the last value in the array.
After that you update the key of the replaced value (last value in array) in the dictionary with the deleted value index. Finally you delete the key and value of the value you want to remove since it doesnt make sense it to be on the dictionary.

```
class RandomizedSet:

    def __init__(self):
        self.container = []
        self.indices = {}
       
        
    def insert(self, val: int) -> bool:
        if val in self.indices:
            return False
        
        self.indices[val] = len(self.container)
        self.container.append(val)
        return True

    def remove(self, val: int) -> bool:
        if val not in self.indices:
            return False
        
        idxOfValueToRemove = self.indices[val]
        lastValue = self.container[-1]
        
        if idxOfValueToRemove < len(self.container)-1:
            self.container[idxOfValueToRemove] = lastValue
            self.indices[lastValue] = idxOfValueToRemove
    
        self.container.pop()
        
        del self.indices[val]
    
        return True
        
        
            

    def getRandom(self) -> int:
         return random.choice(list(self.container))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and wrote

https://github.com/robtandy/randomdict

I hope it helps you!  It provides O(1) access to random keys, values or items.

Comment: Posting a link to external source is not advisable, because then can break in the future. i would suggest you to provide some explanation here and give reference.

Comment: That said, I think this is actually the best solution code-wise. It's clean and doesn't seem to have any major algorithmic drawbacks. There is a bug (fixed easily but in an un-merged PR) to watch out for.

Comment: As @zplizzi suggests, `randomdict` **is the optimal solution.** By compare to @ninjagecko's [otherwise useful solution that internally maintains three (!) dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/users/711085/ninjagecko), `randomdict` only internally maintains one dictionary and a list of 2-tuples. Yes, it's unfortunate that this answer effectively reduces to an HTTP 301 URL redirect – but such is the nature of the open-source code beast. Sometimes, the best implementation already exists as a black-box package. This is one of those times.

Comment: Actually... *maybe not.* `randomdict` deletions are O(n), as the underlying implementation deletes from an internal `list`. This is the classic space versus time tradeoff. Generally, we prefer consuming space to save time – which makes `randomdict` suboptimal for the general case. Nonetheless, `randomdict` space consumption *does* scale significantly better for larger dictionary sizes. `</shrug>`