# random.choice broken with dicts

Tags: python, random, dictionary

The `random.choice` input is supposed to be a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable). This causes odd behavior with a `dict`, which is not a sequence type but can be subscripted like one:

```
>>> d = {0: 'spam', 1: 'eggs', 3: 'potato'}
>>> random.choice(d)
'spam'
>>> random.choice(d)
'eggs'
>>> random.choice(d)
'spam'
>>> random.choice(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 274, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
KeyError: 2
```

Additionally `random.choice` doesn't work at all on a `set`, and some other containers in the `collections` module.

Is there a good reason why `random.choice(d)` shouldn't just work in the obvious way, returning a random key?

I considered `random.choice(list(d))` and `random.sample(d, 1)[0]` but hope there may be more efficient methods. Can `random.choice` be improved without degrading the current behavior on sequences?

Comment: Well, really… given a `dict`, how would *you* pick a random value? It would have to be built into `dict` to be more efficient than `d[random.choice(d.keys())]` in general.

Comment: @Rynah Instead of this: `d[random.choice(d.keys())]`, I think this makes more sense: `random.choice(d.values())`.

Comment: @rynah My opinion is that `random.choice(d)` would pick a random key, not a random value.  This would be more consistent with the way the `in` and `for` keywords operate on keys of dicts.  You would use `random.choice(d.values())` if you wanted a random value (which, incidentally, wouldn't work on python 3).

Comment: It would still need to be built into `dict` to be any more efficient, as @rrenaud noted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see [this thread](http://bugs.python.org/issue1551113) on the Python bug tracker from 2006 about random.choice not working for sets.  It's algorithmically possible to make it work with the same asymptotic efficiency, but it would require either custom support from the set/dict data structures, or a new method in the interface.  The python devs don't deem it needed.

Comment: what about, then, a way to make it work sanely with dicts/sets but transparently remaining same efficiency for sequences?

Comment: @wim I think you need custom implementation to keep same efficiency, something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840901/python-get-random-key-in-a-dictionary-in-o1. You can always choose `dict.keys()` or `list(set)` depending on your demand, but I guess that's not what you want.

Comment: This comment from Tim Peters is telling: "The unwritten promise is that choice(s) on a sequence of length N will take O(1) time and O(1) space."

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution if you just want the top layer of values from a dict.

I am sure you could go ham  on this if you wanted to.

Not a perfect solution but it is a workaround preventing you from getting the weird errors that come up. I hope the implement a way to do this in the future with specification of what layer  1, 2, 3 etc. (for nested dictionaries).

### Example "str":"str"

```py
from random import choice

DictionaryOfItems = {'good': 'steak', 'salty': 'eggs', 'yummy': 'bacon', 'delicious': 'hashbrowns', 'tasty': 'orange juice'}
dictList = []

for i in DictionaryOfItems.keys():  # Create the dictionary list to choose from.
    dictList.extend([i])

a = choice(dictList)  # Set the choice.
b = DictionaryOfItems.get(a)   # get he details of the dictionary item.
print(f"{a}: {b}")   # print the name of the dict key & details.
# tasty: orange juice
print(f"{b}")   # print the name of the selected dictionary value & details.
# orange juice
```

### Example As A Function

```py
from random import choice

def getTopLevelDictionaryValues(dictionary):
    if isinstance(dictionary, dict):
        dictList = []
        for i in DictionaryOfItems.keys():  # Create the dictionary list to choose from.
            dictList.extend([i])
        a = choice(dictList)  # Set the choice.
        b = DictionaryOfItems.get(a)   # get he details of the dictionary item.
    return a, b

DictionaryOfItems = {0: 'steak', 1: 'eggs', 2: 'bacon', 3: 'hashbrowns', 4: 'orange juice'}

a, b = getTopLevelDictionaryValues(DictionaryOfItems)

print(f"{a}: {b}")   # print the name of the dict key & details.
# 3: hashbrowns
print(f"{b}")   # print the name of the selected dictionary value & details.
# hashbrowns


DictionaryOfItems = {'good': 'steak', 'salty': 'eggs', 'yummy': 'bacon', 'delicious': 'hashbrowns', 'tasty': 'orange juice'}
a, b = getTopLevelDictionaryValues(DictionaryOfItems)

print(f"{a}: {b}")   # print the name of the dict key & details.
# good: steak
print(f"{b}")   # print the name of the selected dictionary value & details.
# steak
```