# Data structure with O(1) random removal and adds for shuffling generator order

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

I need a data structure that lets you add elements and remove them randomly in `O(1)` time.

The reason for this that I need to shuffle data from a generator, but I can't load everything into memory at the same time due to size.

This is an example of usage, which automatically shuffles the order of the results generated by a generator expression without loading everything into memory:

```
def generator_shuffler(generator)
    a = magical_data_structure_described_above
    for i in generator:
        a.add(i)
        if len(a) > 10: yield a.poprandom()
```

Initially I tried a python `set()`, however from here: [Set.pop() isn't random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017188/set-pop-isnt-random/21017304), it seems that `set()` doesn't actually remove the items in an arbitrary order. How would I implement the data structure with the above usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to pop randomly, why don't you just use a list and implement pop by swapping the last element with some randomly-selected element and then dropping the new last element? That won't preserve the order of the remaining elements in the data structure, but "pop randomly" and "shuffle" suggest that you don't really care.

Answer (score 1):

Finding and removing a random element in a collection is generally [`O(k)`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) when using `pop`, however, you can modify the action so that the list is shuffled when checking for length, that way, both the `add` and `pop` operations remain `O(1)`:

```
import random

class RandomStack:
   def __init__(self, _d = None):
      self.stack = _d if _d else []
   def __len__(self):
      random.shuffle(self.stack)
      return len(self.stack)
   def add(self, _val):
      self.stack.append(_val)
   def poprandom(self):
      return self.stack.pop()


a = RandomStack()
for i in range(16):
  a.add(i)
  if len(a) > 10:
     val = a.poprandom()
     print(val)
```

Output:

```
2
4
9
0
6
12
```