# python a set of all numeric types.do pop(),not output randomly

Tags: python

当一个集合中的全部类型为数值时，pop()将升序输出，这一点不明白，集合不是无序的吗？

translation：

When all the types in a collection are numeric, pop() will output in ascending order.I don't know why, isn't the set unordered?

`s = {2,5,3,7,0}
for i in range(5):
    print(s.pop())`

output:
0
2
3
5
7

Comment: I have found a similar question in this topic, it could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/dictionaries-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017188/set-pop-isnt-random

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't occur if the numbers are higher

```
>>> l=list(range(655360, 6553600))
>>> for _ in range(20):
...  el = ra.choice(l)
...  s.add(el)
...  print(el)
... 
3589721
2762448
1543072
4489208
5381194
4181645
1470069
6256052
5833067
6288785
3707357
1414093
3347945
1358111
1754489
4503096
3424305
2233038
4817376
3941735
>>> for _ in range(10):
...  print(s.pop())
... 
4181645
6288785
1358111
1543072
3424305
6256052
4503096
5381194
1414093
2233038
```

It's a Python implementation detail and you should not rely on it.

As recommended in the comments, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017188/set-pop-isnt-random)