# Python set pop: how does the element to be popped get chosen?

Tags: random, set, python-3.8

I want to understand how I can control the "random seed" that's used in `set.pop` to select the arbitrary element to be popped.

Consider this example:

```
>>> for _ in range(5):
...   x = {b'a', b'b', b'c'}
...   print(x.pop())
... 
b'a'
b'a'
b'a'
b'a'
b'a'
```

It seems as though the process for popping an element from the `x` set is deterministic. However, there is something set under the hood that fixes this deterministic behaviour. If I run this from another terminal (i.e. another python session), I get a different, but still deterministic result:

```
>>> for _ in range(5):
...   x = {b'a', b'b', b'c'}
...   print(x.pop())
... 
b'c'
b'c'
b'c'
b'c'
b'c'
```

How can I have reproducibility across different python processes for the `set.pop` method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set.pop() isn't random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017188/set-pop-isnt-random)

Comment: It does not answer my question, as the answer in the question you link @pjs does not show how to have reproducibility across different python processes.

Comment: The linked Q&A tell you that it's not a random process, so PRNG seeds have nothing to do with it. One of the answers points out that the use of "arbitrary" in the spec means the implementation can do whatever it wants, which in turn implies that the built-in `set` behavior is not controllable by you.

Comment: I highly doubt that the arbitrariness cannot be controlled by me. I wonder if this has to do with the set being a hashmap, and this it uses the internal `hash` Python function, which is also arbitrary across Python sessions

Comment: @VladimirVargas: You may be looking for the `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED

Comment: @MarkDickinson could you expand your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?