# Design a data struture for integers of range 1 to 1000(non repeating) for basic operations in O(1)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

**Design a data struture for integers of range 1 to 1000(non repeating) for following operations.**
1)Insertion

2)Deletions

3)Search

**4)int Anyvalid() ->   This should return any valid/present number present at the time.**
Example if 1,5,7
are present,then return any of the 3 number.

All the operations should be 0(1)/Constant time.

I thought of bit vector but it give 0(n) in case of AnyvalidElement()..
for rest all it works in 0(1).

Comment: To nitpick, if the range 1-1000 is constant, anything linear in the size of the range is in O(1).

Comment: Seems like a simpler version of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9575905/21727

Comment: int anyvalid()? can return anyvalid integer? If yes. Just store the minimum element present in the DS and every element stores the pointer to the next minimum. The pointers are for deletion and just return minimum element in anyvalid(). Bit vector structure btw!

Comment: Array of pointers to linked list elements will do fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a doubly linked list and an array of pointers to the list nodes.

- Insert n: Add n to the front of the list, array[n] = pointer to newly
  added node.
- Delete n: Use array to jump to the correct node in the
  list and remove it. Set array[n] = NULL;
- Search n: check if array[n] != NULL
- AnyValid: return front of the list